# Forcing aggressive supersampling in a raytracer

Tags: antialiasing, raytracing, blender, povray

Does anyone know how to force a large amount of supersampling in Blender or POV-Ray, say 100 samples per pixel, at least?  This is for a research project that is heavily dependent on sub-pixel artifacts.  Rendering a large image and shrinking it will not work because a few critical pixels will be very bright, and the output values will be clipped.  They would need to be averaged *before* clipping.

Blender seems to support only [5, 8, 11, or 16 samples](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc%3aManual/Render/Oversampling_%28Antialiasing%29), since it uses predefined sampling patterns.

POV-Ray [does not support non-adaptive supersampling methods](http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.1/223/), which is necessary because there is a large variation within pixels that may not be apparent from variation between pixels.

Comment: Can you render a large image and shrink it by averaging pixels instead of clipping?

Comment: The pixels values would be clipped when they're output into the large image.  I have no control over that; most image formats do not allow values outside the range 0-255.

Comment: It seems POV-Ray supports HDR output which gives 32 bits per color per pixel

Comment: Is this really a programming question, or just a question about how to use particular packages?  Can you rephrase it as a programming question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the mesh camera in the latest POV-Ray beta (3.7.beta.39). This allows you to specify an arbitrary number of rays per pixel by defining an appropriate mesh ([docs are here](http://wiki.povray.org/content/Documentation%3aReference_Section_3#Mesh_projection)).

There are some macros and sample scenes included with the dist. If you're not sure on how to create a mesh camera that does what you want, try asking in the povray.beta-test group at news.povray.org. A simple approach would be to create a mesh representing a standard camera (one face per pixel) and instantiate it into the scene 100 times (assuming 100 samples per pixel), jittering it slightly each time (this can be easily done in a macro).

Also, Jaime Vives Piqueres has a good (but work-in-progress) [demo page here](http://www.ignorancia.org/en/index.php?page=mesh-camera). See in particular the section titled 'Custom Cameras'.